# Java / convert ISO-8601 (2010-12-16T13:33:50.513852Z) to Date object

Tags: java, date, iso

How to parse a String in [ISO 8601](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj3v-75kKjTAhXINiYKHbghDUsQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FISO_8601&usg=AFQjCNHiu7VQuZb3qSt_mWulsOWb3eWa_g&sig2=v1HyXyVwFQmEVhDJIliFSg) format with Zulu time?

```
javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime("2010-12-16T13:33:50.513852Z")
```

returns

```
IllegalArgumentException: '2010-12-16T13:33:50.513852Z' weist ein falsches Format auf.
```

Which mean something like wrong format, anyone have a clue what iss wrong in here?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the format, It works nicely.

Comment: FYI: Later duplicated by [Parsing ISO 8601 date format like 2015-06-27T13:16:37.363Z in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31090946/642706)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.parse( "2010-12-16T13:33:50.513852Z" )
```

---

## java.time

The newer java.time classes can handle this string input.

The `Z` on the end is short for `Zulu` and means [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), an offset of zero `+00:00`.

### `Instant`

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2010-12-16T13:33:50.513852Z" );
```

### Time zone

You may want to apply a time zone `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`. Search Stack Overflow for those class names to learn more, as well as for classes `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`.

### Conversion

Best to avoid the troublesome old legacy class of `java.util.Date`. But if you insist, call the new conversion methods added to the old classes.

```
java.util.Date date = java.util.Date.from( instant );
```

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

It works for me try [ide online](http://ideone.com/afT68)

Output is :

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT+00:00",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2010,MONTH=11,WEEK_OF_YEAR=1,WEEK_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_MONTH=16,DAY_OF_YEAR=1,DAY_OF_WEEK=5,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=13,MINUTE=33,SECOND=50,MILLISECOND=513,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=0]
```

Comment: Link is broken. :-(

Comment: Update: This terrible class has now been supplanted by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 1):

If the target Data Type is "**ZonedDateTime**", you can use the date-formatter "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSX". Example code as follows:

```
    public ZonedDateTime convertStringToZonedDateTime() {
       String inputString = "2010-12-16T13:33:50.513852Z";
       DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSX");
       ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(inputString, formatter);
       return zdt; //Output ZonedDateTime object is 2010-12-16T13:33:50.513852Z
}
```

**Attention! If the input date-String has 0 as second and milli-second, for example "2010-12-16T13:00:00.000000Z", then the output ZonedDateTime object is "2010-12-16T13:00Z", even through it looks strange without second and milli-second, it is still a leagl ZonedDateTime.**

If the target Data Type is "**Instant**":

```
    public Instant convertStringToInstant() {
       String inputString = "2010-12-16T13:33:50.513852Z";
       Instant instant = Instant.parse(inputString);
       return instant; //Output Instant object is 2010-12-16T13:33:50.513852Z
}
```

Comment: Also the one-arg `ZonedDateTime.parse` method parses the string without any explicit formatter, `ZonedDateTime.parse(inputString)`.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted works fine in my jre. Probably you defined your own DatatypeConverter (with german exception texts...!) and this specific DatatypeConverter cannot parse this date.

Do a codesearch for this code: `DatatypeConverter.setDatatypeConverter(` - there you will probably find your custom implementation of the "DatatypeConverterInterface" - which will then probably lead you to your bug.

Alternatively you can search for `weist ein falsches Format auf.` (because that exception text is not part of the jre)

Viel Erfolg ;)