# Parse Date Format

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following `DataFrame` containing the `date format` - `yyyyMMddTHH:mm:ss+UTC`

#### Data Preparation

```
sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame([("20201021T00:00:00+0530",),
                               ("20211011T00:00:00+0530",),
                               ("20200212T00:00:00+0300",),
                               ("20211021T00:00:00+0530",),
                               ("20211021T00:00:00+0900",),
                               ("20211021T00:00:00-0500",)
                              ]
                              ,['timestamp'])


sparkDF.show(truncate=False)

+----------------------+
|timestamp             |
+----------------------+
|20201021T00:00:00+0530|
|20211011T00:00:00+0530|
|20200212T00:00:00+0300|
|20211021T00:00:00+0530|
|20211021T00:00:00+0900|
|20211021T00:00:00-0500|
+----------------------+
```

I m aware of the `date format` to parse and convert the values to `DateType`

#### Timestamp Parsed

```
sparkDF.select(F.to_date(F.col('timestamp'),"yyyyMMdd'T'HH:mm:ss+0530").alias('timestamp_parsed')).show()

+----------------+
|timestamp_parsed|
+----------------+
|      2020-10-21|
|      2021-10-11|
|            null|
|      2021-10-21|
|            null|
|            null|
+----------------+
```

As you can see , its specific to `+0530` strings , I m aware of the fact that I can use multiple patterns and `coalesce` the first non-null values

##### Multiple Patterns & Coalesce

```
sparkDF.withColumn('p1',F.to_date(F.col('timestamp'),"yyyyMMdd'T'HH:mm:ss+0530"))\
       .withColumn('p2',F.to_date(F.col('timestamp'),"yyyyMMdd'T'HH:mm:ss+0900"))\
       .withColumn('p3',F.to_date(F.col('timestamp'),"yyyyMMdd'T'HH:mm:ss-0500"))\
       .withColumn('p4',F.to_date(F.col('timestamp'),"yyyyMMdd'T'HH:mm:ss+0300"))\
       .withColumn('timestamp_parsed',F.coalesce(F.col('p1'),F.col('p2'),F.col('p3'),F.col('p4')))\
       .drop(*['p1','p2','p3','p4'])\
       .show(truncate=False)

+----------------------+----------------+
|timestamp             |timestamp_parsed|
+----------------------+----------------+
|20201021T00:00:00+0530|2020-10-21      |
|20211011T00:00:00+0530|2021-10-11      |
|20200212T00:00:00+0300|2020-02-12      |
|20211021T00:00:00+0530|2021-10-21      |
|20211021T00:00:00+0900|2021-10-21      |
|20211021T00:00:00-0500|2021-10-21      |
+----------------------+----------------+
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this, as there might be a bunch of other `UTC` within the data source, is there a standard `UTC TZ` available within Spark to parse all the cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you have got the 2nd argument of your to_date function wrong which is causing null values in your output

the +530 in your timestamp is the Zulu value which just denotes how many hours and mins ahead (for +) or behind (for  -) the current timestamp is withrespect to UTC.
Please refer to the response by Basil here [Java / convert ISO-8601 (2010-12-16T13:33:50.513852Z) to Date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525850/java-convert-iso-8601-2010-12-16t133350-513852z-to-date-object) This link has full details available for the same.

To answer your question if you replace `+0530` by `Z` it should solve your problem.

Here is the spark code in scala that I tried and worked:

```
val data = Seq("20201021T00:00:00+0530",
                               "20211011T00:00:00+0530",
                               "20200212T00:00:00+0300",
                               "20211021T00:00:00+0530",
                               "20211021T00:00:00+0900",
                               "20211021T00:00:00-0500")

import spark.implicits._
val sparkDF = data.toDF("custom_time")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val spark_DF2 = sparkDF.withColumn("new_timestamp", to_date($"custom_time", "yyyyMMdd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"))

spark_DF2.show(false)
```

here is the snapshot of the output. As you can see there are no null values.
[image: output]

Comment: This is helpful Vikas , also the explanation around the Zulu thing

Answer (score 2):

You can usually use `x`, `X` or `Z` for offset pattern as you can find on [Spark date pattern documentation page](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html). You can then parse your date with the following complete pattern: `yyyyMMdd'T'HH:mm:ssxx`

However, if you use those kind of offset patterns, your date will be first converted in UTC format, meaning all timestamp with a positive offset will be matched to the previous day. For instance `"20201021T00:00:00+0530"` will be matched to `2020-10-20` using `to_date` with the previous pattern.

If you want to get displayed date as a date, ignoring offset, you should first extract date string from complete timestamp string using [`regexp_extract`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract.html) function, then perform `to_date`.

If you take your example `"20201021T00:00:00+0530"`, what you want to extract with a regexp is `20201021` part and apply `to_date` on it. You can do it with the following pattern: `^(\\d+)`. If you're interested, you can find how to build other patterns in [java's Pattern documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

So your code should be:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

sparkDF.select(
  F.to_date(
    F.regexp_extract(F.col('timestamp'), '^(\\d+)', 0), 'yyyyMMdd'
  ).alias('timestamp_parsed')
).show()
```

And with your input you will get:

```
+----------------+
|timestamp_parsed|
+----------------+
|2020-10-21      |
|2021-10-11      |
|2020-02-12      |
|2021-10-21      |
|2021-10-21      |
|2021-10-21      |
+----------------+
```

Comment: The SQL Ref link was helpful , I had seen that link , but couldn't remember where it was buried in the Spark API docs , Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can create "udf" in spark and use it. Below is the code in scala.

```
import spark.implicits._

//just to create the dataset for the example you have given
val data = Seq(
  ("20201021T00:00:00+0530"),
  ("20211011T00:00:00+0530"),
  ("20200212T00:00:00+0300"),
  ("20211021T00:00:00+0530"),
  ("20211021T00:00:00+0900"),
  ("20211021T00:00:00-0500"))

val dataset = data.toDF("timestamp")
val udfToDateUTC = functions.udf((epochMilliUTC: String) => {
  val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
  val res = OffsetDateTime.parse(epochMilliUTC, formatter).withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
  res.toString()
})

dataset.select(dataset.col("timestamp"),udfToDateUTC(dataset.col("timestamp")).alias("timestamp_parsed")).show(false)

//output
+----------------------+-----------------+
|timestamp             |timestamp_parsed |
+----------------------+-----------------+
|20201021T00:00:00+0530|2020-10-20T18:30Z|
|20211011T00:00:00+0530|2021-10-10T18:30Z|
|20200212T00:00:00+0300|2020-02-11T21:00Z|
|20211021T00:00:00+0530|2021-10-20T18:30Z|
|20211021T00:00:00+0900|2021-10-20T15:00Z|
|20211021T00:00:00-0500|2021-10-21T05:00Z|
+----------------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: UDF's can get difficult to control in terms of speed , especially if the data volume is enormous

Answer (score -1):

from pyspark.sql.functions import date_format

customer_data  = select("<column_name>",date_format("<column_name>",'yyyyMMdd').cast('customer')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).