# Parse different formats of date in string format to date format pyspark when clause

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

Need to convert this format to

```
name,code,DATE_invoice
Ram,E01,09/29/2018
Mara,E02,07/14/2017
Test,E03,01/01/18
```

this:

```
name,code,DATE_invoice
Ram,E01,2018-09-29
Mara,E02,2017-07-14
Test,E03,2018-01-01
```

Comment: What did you try and where did you encounter problems?

Answer (score 0):

If the column is already a date, this should do the job:

```
df = df.withColumn('DATE_invoice', date_format(col("DATE_invoice"), "yyyy-MM-dd")))
```

Comment: @

Robert Kossendey This returns null

Answer (score 0):

To Parse different data formats you can utilise [to_date](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_date.html) along with [coalesce](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce.html)

You can utilise the same approach towards multiple patterns within your dataset , and example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69187606/parse-date-format)

#### Data preparation

```
input_str = """
Ram,E01,09/29/2018,
Mara,E02,07/14/2017,
Test,E03,01/01/18
""".split(",")

input_values = list(map(lambda x: x.strip() if x.strip() != 'null' else None, input_str))

cols = list(map(lambda x: x.strip() if x.strip() != 'null' else None, "name,code,DATE_invoice".split(",")))
            
n = len(input_values)
n_col = 3

input_list = [tuple(input_values[i:i+n_col]) for i in range(0,n,n_col)]

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(input_list, cols)

sparkDF.show()

+----+----+------------+
|name|code|DATE_invoice|
+----+----+------------+
| Ram| E01|  09/29/2018|
|Mara| E02|  07/14/2017|
|Test| E03|    01/01/18|
+----+----+------------+
```

#### To Date and Coalesce

```
sql.sql("set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy=LEGACY")

sparkDF.withColumn('p1',F.to_date(F.col('DATE_invoice'),"MM/dd/yyyy"))\
       .withColumn('p2',F.to_date(F.col('DATE_invoice'),"MM/dd/yy"))\
       .withColumn('DATE_invoice_parsed',F.coalesce(F.col('p1'),F.col('p2')))\
       .drop(*['p1','p2'])\
       .show(truncate=False)

+----+----+------------+-------------------+
|name|code|DATE_invoice|DATE_invoice_parsed|
+----+----+------------+-------------------+
|Ram |E01 |09/29/2018  |2018-09-29         |
|Mara|E02 |07/14/2017  |2017-07-14         |
|Test|E03 |01/01/18    |0018-01-01         |
+----+----+------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Instead of 0018 I need to showcase it as 2018

Comment: for cases `dd/mm/yy` , you additionally need to supply the year and merge it within with `DATE_invoice` to parse it correctly

Comment: Can you please provide me with some Example ?