# How to add multiple delimiters to date format in spark-sql

Tags: sql, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
spark.sql("select CASE WHEN ((from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dt,'yyyyMMdd'),'yyyyMMdd') == dt) or  (from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dt,'MMddyyyy'),'MMddyyyy') == dt)) then dt else '' end as dt, case WHEN ((from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dt,'yyyyMMdd'),'yyyyMMdd') == dt) or  (from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dt,'MMddyyyy'),'MMddyyyy') == dt)) then 'Y' else 'dt: should be present in \"yyyyMMdd\" or \"MMddyyyy\" format' end as dt_flag from input").show(false)
```

In the above code I've written the query for accepting two formats
yyyyMMdd and MMddyyyy

In this , multiple delimiters should be accepted like no delimiters,periods,commas,slashes,dashes
for date type.

I'm not sure how to add those, please help me on this! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple columns based out of your accepted `Date Formats`

Once done , you can use [coalesce](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce.html) to club them together

An example of the approach is demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69187606/parse-date-format)

Comment: I think in that withcolumn is used . How can I incorporate it with my query?. can you please show that in my query. @Vaebhav